# System calls in Linux that can be used to delete files

Tags: linux, system-calls, delete-file, file-handling, unlink

What are the system calls that can be used to delete a file on Linux? I am not referring to just the system calls used by the libc-wrapper(which in-turn are used by command line tools).

Other than `unlink` and `unlinkat` what are the system calls that could be used to delete files on a Linux machine?

Comment: I don't understand what you're searching for! What's your need, what are you trying to do? Or why do `unlink`not be enough?

Comment: I'm trying to monitor all file deletions across my system for a pet project. Most applications use `unlink` and `unlinkat`, but I want to know if there are other system calls that can be used to delete files.

Comment: I don't really understand why there are 2 votes to close this question, it is related to programming.

Comment: @uki If you want to monitor filesystem events in general, consider using the [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) API.

Answer (score 4):

`rename()` and `renameat()` can be used to delete a file by renaming another file over it.

If you consider making a file empty to be a form of deletion, a variety of system calls, including `truncate()` and `open()` with `O_TRUNC`, can do that.