# What's an efficient way to get a list of the files which were modified when a command was run?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, inotify

My team has a program which generates lots of temporary files when it runs and deletes them once it's finished.  Unfortunately, if the program is interrupted that means that these files get left in arbitrary places within the program's directory tree (usually alongside the individual scripts which created the files).

In order to make cleanup simpler for these cases we'd like to refactor the code to place all of the temporary files within a single designated directory.

The first step seems to be to get a list of all the temporary files which we're generating.  I've managed to accomplish this as follows:

1. Open a BASH shell
2. `cd` to the program's directory
3. run `inotifywait -m --timefmt "%F %T" --format "%T %w %f %e" -r . >> modified_files.log`
4. Open another BASH shell
5. Run the program in the new shell
6. Wait several hours for the program to finish running
7. Terminate the `inotifywait` process in the first shell.  `modified_files.log` will now contain millions of lines (hundreds of megabytes) of output like this:

   ```
   2019-07-23 12:28:33 ./project/some_dir/ some_file OPEN
   2019-07-23 12:28:33 ./project/some_dir/ some_file MODIFY
   2019-07-23 12:28:33 ./project/some_dir/ some_file CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE
   2019-07-23 12:28:33 ./project/some_other_dir/ some_other_file OPEN
   2019-07-23 12:28:33 ./project/some_other_dir/ some_other_file MODIFY
   2019-07-23 12:28:33 ./project/some_other_dir/ some_other_file CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE
   ```
8. Pass `modified_files.log` to the following script:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash -e

   # We'll store paths to the modified files here without any duplicates
   declare -A UNIQUE_FILES

   # Iterate over every line of output in modified_files.log
   while IFS= read -r line; do

       # In the first line from the output example this would find ./project/some_dir/
       directory="$(grep -Po ".*?\s.*?\s\K.*?(?=\s.*)" <<< "$line")"

       # In the first line from the output example this would find some_file
       file="$(grep -Po ".*?\s.*?\s.*?\s\K.*?(?=\s.*)" <<< "$line")"

       path="${directory}${file}"

       # Only record the path from this output line if we haven't already recorded it
       if [[ -n "$path" ]] && [[ -z "${UNIQUE_FILES["$path"]}" ]]; then
           UNIQUE_FILES["$path"]=1
       fi
   done < "$1"

   # Save all of the recorded paths as separate lines within a single 'list' variable
   for unique_file in "${!UNIQUE_FILES[@]}"; do
       list="${list}"$'\n'"${unique_file}"
   done

   # Sort the 'list' variable to make the list of paths visually easier to read
   list="$(echo "$list" | sort)"

   # Print the paths of all the modified files
   echo "$list"
   ```

This works, but it takes about a minute to parse for every megabyte of output produced by inotifywait.  I feel like there ought to be a much faster way to do this next time the need arises.  I'm hoping for solutions which address either:

- Inefficiencies in the grep commands shown above (IE: perhaps using calls to sed/awk instead?)
- Inefficiencies with the parsing script in general
- Inefficiencies with the inotifywait command which I'm using (IE: remove the timestamps or call it with some special flags to reduce the verbosity)
- Inefficiences with the general process listed above

Comment: I recommend looking into a cleanup trap on `EXIT` instead, like this: http://redsymbol.net/articles/bash-exit-traps/

Comment: @BenjaminW. We do have one, but it only cleans up a particular directory.  We're not even sure where all the other temporary files are going so it's difficult to clean them up right now.  AFAIK a SIGKILL (or a power outage for that matter) will also bypass an exit trap, but that's another problem.

Comment: `touch ./canary; run-the-programm`. Then `find ./ -anewer canari -delete`

Comment: You're relying on your filenames not containing blanks; this should have the same output as your script: `awk '{print $3 $4}' modified_files.log | sort -u`

Comment: @LéaGris That seems like a reasonable solution for cleaning up the files which were written.  It would almost work for detecting the temporary files with a `-print` argument on the end (IE: run it once and see which files it deletes), but unfortunately it can't detect files which have already been deleted.

Comment: `strace -o >(sed -n 's/^[^"]*"\(.*\)".*$/\1/p' | sort -u >usedfiles) -f -e openat ... -- prog ...`

Comment: @AlexJohnson Obviously find will not detect already deleted files. Then why are you bothering to have them listed for your cleanup?

Comment: rewrite the whole `while` loop as an `awk` script. Only one process being started, not N(um of lines)*4 (maybe more). Good luck.

Comment: @jhnc Glancing through the man pages this looks like it covers all of my steps at once.  Feel free to elaborate on it and post it as an answer!

Comment: @LéaGris I'd rather not have to search for the files every time.  If we know what temporary files are being written then we can hunt down the bits of code which create them and change them to place the files in a single shared location.  Then all we have to do is delete everything in that location on program start instead of searching around for stray files.

Comment: @AlexJohnson : For each single line of the input file, you create two child processes! No surprise that it takes quite long, if the input file is big.

Comment: @user1934428 yes, for some reason inotifywait separates the directory and file names with a space.  I couldn't find a simple way to capture two groups at the same time with grep so I called it twice and appended them to format out that space.  In hindsight it might have been more efficient to capture them both in a single group and then use BASH parameter expansion to strip the whitespace out without another subprocess call.  Perhaps sed also has a way to do the search+strip in a single subprocess, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @AlexJohnson : You could apply the bash regexp operator to pick the individual parts of the line you are interested in. In any case, avoid creating even a single child processes within a loop over a huge file.

Comment: @jhnc - I had to tweak the sed expression a bit (`s/^[0-9]*\s*openat(.*,\s"\(.*\)",\s.*WR.*$/\1/p`), but your solution worked perfectly for some jobs which ran last night.  I'll describe+post it as an answer in a couple of days unless you'd still like to.

Comment: @AlexJohnson, ...btw, as a note -- you'll get orders-of-magnitude performance enhancements just from using native bash string manipulation in your inner loop, and **not** (ever!) running command substitutions, pipes, or other operations that involve forking per line of input read. (It's fine to run one `grep` that processes 10,000 lines; it's not at all fine to run 10,000 separate copies of `grep`, one per line). Fortunately, bash has very robust string manipulation primitives, so you don't *need* any of the `grep` bits in this code.

Comment: Rewrite your regexes from PCRE to POSIX ERE, and `[[ $string =~ $re ]]` will give you a very fast in-process match, putting the resulting match groups in the `BASH_REMATCH` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**strace** may work, although [it can cause performance issues](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-05-11/strace-wow-much-syscall.html).

You would look for files that have been opened for writing, or perhaps you could just check for files that are deleted/unlinked ( cf. [System calls in Linux that can be used to delete files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35610657/10971581) )

Filenames in strace output may be given relative to the current directory so you may want to log chdir() too.

The basic invocation would be:

```
strace -f -o LOGFILE -e WhatToTrace -- PROGRAM ARGUMENTS
```

Examples of syscalls to include in **WhatToTrace** are:

- `openat,open,creat` - trace file access/creation
- `mkdirat,mkdir` - trace directory creation
- `unlinkat,unlink,rmdir` - find deleted files and directories
- `chdir` - log when current working directory changes
- `renameat,rename` - find overwritten files

Once you have your **LOGFILE**, you can write a simple script to process the paths that have been recorded.

Comment: If you want something much, *much* faster than strace, look at sysdig and other clients to the eBPF subsystem. Whereas strace traces a single process with maybe 500% overhead (if you're lucky!), sysdig traces *your entire operating system at once* with on the scale of 3% overhead (dumping events into a ring buffer that's shuffled into userspace for later filtering/analysis).

Comment: (sysdig isn't *just* an eBPF client, but the eBPF version of their probe is more reliable with recent kernels -- though they reportedly just found a fix for that today, it's not yet merged, much less in a release).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can sysdig be used as an ordinary user without root to load kernel modules or other special permissions?

Comment: Sysadmin cooperation is needed. (Since it isn't restricted to tracing just one user's processes, that'd be a major security vulnerability otherwise; anyone could snoop on *everyone else's* processes, data entry, etc). That said, there's a filter language available plus lua support for more advanced filters, so a sysadmin could easily stream a trace with just one user's events to somewhere that user could read it...

Comment: For the record: running my program with strace took 27% longer than it did without strace.  sysdig looks like a good tool to turn to in situations where there's more of an impact though.